# Is there a way to download the SonarLint report generated in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

SonarLint analyzes the code and generates the report fine within it's SonarLint Report window. However, I am not able find any option to extract/export this report.

I also tried looking for any setting in the preferences but could not find any.

[image: SolarLint window in eclipse]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question on official SonarLint forum and got to know that it is not possible.
Suggested to use SonarQube / SonarCloud tool for reporting purpose.

Comment: You could just right click on an issue , select all, then right click copy and paste them  where required..